# Polymorphism in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, polymorphism

In VB.NET, say I have a function

```
Public Function Foo(ByVal currentShape as Shape)
```

Instead up passing in a `Shape` object, I pass in a subclass of `Shape` called `Square` like such:

```
Dim square As Square = new Square()
Foo(square)
```

Do I need to convert my `Square` object to a `Shape` object before passing it in? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: I did, but the root of my question is a little more complicated than this example. The `Foo` function is actually a web service call and the class I pass into the function is a subclass of what it expects. By doing this, I get a serialization error. Im new to VB, so I was thinking maybe I needed to cast or convert the object before passing it in.

Comment: Aside: code such as this `Dim x As Foo = New Foo()` can (and *should*) be written simpler as `Dim x As New Foo()` in VB (or, if you’ve got `Option Infer` enabled, equivalently `Dim x = New Foo()`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Square` *is-a* `Shape`.
You don't need to convert anything.

All subclasses are implicitly convertible to their superclasses.

Comment: Ugh - beat me be a whole four seconds ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to perform a conversion yourself. The value of `square` can be converted using a *reference conversion* to a value of type `Shape` (it's still a reference). This does *not* create a new object - it just looks at the object in a different way :) `Foo` will only be able to access members *declared* in `Shape`,  although they may be *overridden* in `Square`.

Any changes made to the object within `Foo` will still be visible via `square` when the method returns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can pass the Square object straight in.